# Synthesis of truncate function

Tags: vhdl

I am using synplify, and wrote a utility library for my project, that contains the following function:

```
function truncate(x: in std_logic_vector; constant length: in integer)
return std_logic_vector is
    variable result : std_logic_vector(length-1 downto 0);
begin
    result := x(length-1 downto 0);
    return result;
end function;
```

However Synplify gives the following error (line 197 is the one where I declare the `result` variable):

> @E:CD866 : utility.vhd(197) | Expression  is not a constant(static)
>   expression

My questions are:

- Why do I get the error? (I thought in synthesis the `function` is inlined and everything is fine)
- How can I work arround it?  (I tried marking the length as const, but that did not work, besides it will screw up the later part.)
- If the workarround is: just write it out, can i formulate `result <= a(a'left downto a'right+cut) & truncate(unsigned(b)+2, cut);` without using additional immediates? (I know that `result <= a(a'left downto a'right+cut) & (b+2)(cut-1 downto 0);` won't work without calculating `cut-1` in an intermediate vector and then using a subset of that vector.)

---

**Important NOTE:**

My design contains a part were I combine two vectors somewhat similar to this (`cut`is an input signal, thus not constant):

```
result <= a(a'left downto a'right+cut) & truncate(b, cut);
```

While I have a feeling that this might be the source of the problem, I do not see why such a contraption should not be synthesizable (after all it is just several multiplexers and cut controls which ones take "bits" from `a`/`b`respectivley.

(The reason is i find `truncate(x, y)` more readable than `x(y-1 downto 0)`, furthermore one could extend this function to work regardless of range direction and offest (e.g. a vector `x` only defined for a range `k downto l` where `l>0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your return value has a dynamic length. In synthesis, this implies a physical bus that has a varying number of bits, which most certainly is not synthesizable. Try padding the return value with zeros so that it can have a constant width...that shouldn't make any difference to the later AND operation.

Comment: I see where you come from. So far I tried using the `&` operator to concat and not the bitwise `and`. I guess I will just write a function for the messy part that introduces a temp signal as mentioned in my editied question.