# Concatination function

Tags: vhdl

In a [prior question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79727/synthesis-of-truncate-function) I asked about a truncate function, which hinted that I should try a function with a static return width.

I am trying to combine two vectors `x` and `y` by taking the first `c` bits from `x` and the remaining `x'length - c` bits from `y`. (I assume `x` and `y` are of equal range). Therefore I wrote the following function, which again yields an error, this time on the line were I assign `result`

```
/*
 Combines two signals by taking bitsFromX bits from x and the rest from y.

 x vector 1 to combine
 y vector 2 to combine, must be of same length as x
 bitsFromX number of bits taken from x
 */
function combine(x: in std_logic_vector; y: in std_logic_vector; bitsFromX: in natural)
return std_logic_vector is
    variable result : std_logic_vector(x'RANGE);
begin
    --assert x'LENGTH= y'LENGTH report "Attempt to combine different length vectors" & lf & "X: " & RANGE'IMAGE(x'RANGE) & "Y: " & RANGE'IMAGE(y'RANGE);
    result := x(x'LEFT downto x'LEFT-bitsFromX+1) & y(y'LEFT-bitsFromX downto y'RIGHT);
    return result;
end function;
```

The error message (from synplify) is:

> Expecting constant expression

I can work arround this by using two assignments:

```
result(x'LEFT downto x'LEFT-bitsFromX+1) := x(x'LEFT downto x'LEFT-bitsFromX+1);
result(y'LEFT-bitsFromX downto y'RIGHT)  := y(y'LEFT-bitsFromX downto y'RIGHT);
```

and would like to understand why this is so? (It a ppears to me that it is the second time I make the same mistake, because I do not understand the reason yet).

As a Bonus: How do I `report` the result of `x'RANGE`, `to_string(x'RANGE)` and `RANGE'IMAGE(x'RANGE)` don't work for me.

Comment: Is the error message appearing during simulation, synthesis, or both? Exactly which line of VHDL is producing the error?

Comment: @JoeHass: error during synthesis (synplify), the assignment of `result` causes the error.